# How can i listen to an event when the user clicks on the vertical scroll bar and moves it up or down

Tags: javascript

I am using this event to detect when the user is scrolling through the page.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log("mouseEvent");
});
```

The problem is that when i hold on the scrollbar and i move it manually (without scrollin on the middle of my mouse) then this is not detected by the browser.

How can i listen to this changes ?

Comment: My guess: You probably can’t. How often/when the scroll event fires, is mostly up to the browser’s discretion.

Comment: just tried to put this event on `document` instead - worked for me.

Comment: @Petar Your code works fine on Firefox on manual scrolling.